# Linq select different column into one

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have 3 table like

```
Person
--------
personname


student
-------
studentid
address
personid


teacher
--------
teacherid
address
personid
```

and my linq query is

```
var p=from p in db.person
    join s in db.student
    on p.personid equals s.personid
    join t in db.teacher
    on p.personid equals t.personid
    select {address=????};
```

How can i select both student and teacher address into one field????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select new { address = s.address + " " + t.address };
```

This should work - change the " " with whatever separator you like.

Comment: I get it and I split it   like this,,,                                                       string[] para=x.address.Split('','\t');      Thank you Lweis.